# Extracting memtraces from c++ programs

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind, mtrace

I'm interested in **extracting memory accesses** of a certain program.

I'm looking for the following list for example on a specific execution:

```
[R\W]  [Address]   [numBytes]     
R         0x0000012d32a21   0x4
```

I already tried valgrind and mtrace, as well as their related tools.

They are all seem to return back a more general statistics or memory-leakage related statistics.

I'm interested in all memory accesses data.

I googled it for hours, and find many papers dealing with that problem, but not a working open source code.

Appreciate your help

Comment: You could try to hook `_sbrk()` yourself (not a big deal if you're a _'H@x0r'_) ...

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [Pin](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool).

From the description:

> Pin is a dynamic binary instrumentation framework for the IA-32 and
>   x86-64 instruction-set architectures that enables the creation of
>   dynamic program analysis tools.

You should be able to find or write a pintool that does what you need.  For example, [this one.](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/62141/Pin/html/index.html#MAddressTrace)  The linked example is almost exactly what you ask for.  You'll need to add an `IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE` and `IARG_MEMORYWRITE_SIZE` to the instrumentation, but that looks pretty trivial to do.

Answer (score 1):

The valgrind lackey tool should give you the needed information.

See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/lk-manual.html
option --trace-mem= [default: no]

Comment: Worked perfectly. Very easy to use. Thanks a lot!